# Can I use currency.js for commercial purposes?

Tags: license, cryptography, bitcoin, cryptomining

I working on a cryptocurrency price tracker. I make use of the `currency.js` library. Can  I use `currency.js` for commercial purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the currency.js [github page](https://github.com/scurker/currency.js/blob/master/license), we can see they use a MIT licence. It says:

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
>   EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
>   NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE
>   LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION
>   OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION
>   WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

So in summary, yes, you can use the software commercially as long as you include the copyright notice.